# how to predict new inputs using a tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, prediction

There are plenty good tutorials on building a tensorflow model and I achieved creating a model with good accuracy. However, there are 2 questions left.

In my dataset there are plenty of classes, I try to illustrate that like this:

```
label - text
--------------------
A - this is a A text
B - this is a B text
C - this is a C text
...
Z - this is a Z text
...
ZA - this is a ZA text
...
```

Now I want to build a network that leans to classify the texts. I understand, that I have to deliver a fixed set of labels, because the net needs to have a fixed count of "output neurons". So, for learning purposes, I started to build a network only for the 3 classes A, B and C. I fed the network only with corresponding rows (A, B, C) and I got a model, that can recognize A, B, C with good accuracy.

Now I want to predict new texts and would like to get an output like this:

```
input text -> predicted label
----------------------------
this is a B text -> B   // successful prediction
this is a xyz text -> ? // cannot be predicted, because not learned
```

How do I achieve the "not predictable" for the not yet learned classes?

All in all my way to get a csv-file with added prediction column might be a little clumsy. Could you show me how to do it better?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_parquet(path)


#print(df)
#label = df['kategorie'].fillna("N/A")
text = df['text'].fillna("")

text_padded = tokenize_and_pad(text)


# Predictions
probability_model = tf.keras.Sequential([model, 
                                         tf.keras.layers.Softmax()])
predictions = probability_model.predict(text_padded)

# get the predicted labels
# I only achieved this with this loop - there must be a more elegant way???
predictedLabels = []
for prediction in predictions:
    labelID = np.argmax(prediction)
    predictedLabel = label_encoder.inverse_transform([labelID])
    predictedLabels.append(predictedLabel)


# add the new column to the dataframe
# the prediction is accurate for the learned labels
# but totally wrong for the labels, that I excluded from the learning
df['predictedLabels'] = predictedLabels

# todo: write to file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, I understand that you need help in two areas:

1. Answer to the question, `How do I achieve the "not predictable" for the not yet learned classes?`:

a. Since you want to consider only 3 Classes, instead of deleting the Rows corresponding to other Classes, you can replace the Names of those Columns with, "Not Predictable" i.e., replace `'D', 'E', 'F', etc..` with `"Not Predictable"`.

b. In the Final `Dense Layer`, change the Number of `Neurons` from 3 to 4, 4th class representing `"Not Predictable"`

2. Answer to the question, How to write `Predictions` to a `CSV` File:

Now that `Predictions` are added as a `Column` in the `DataFrame, df` you can write it to a CSV File using the command,

```
df.to_csv('My_Predictions.csv')
```

For more information about this command, please refer [this link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

The way you are accessing the `Labels` looks elegant.

Please let me know if you face any other `error` and I will be Happy to help you.

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!

Comment: Thank you for the explaination. Can I add a probability for the correctness of a prediction to each row?